# Pages in subdirectory redirect only to that subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my site in two directories, default is on `root` and the other is `root/en`. Is there a way to tell in .htaccess that every link we click on `root/en` version redirects to `root/en`?

For example I have a link on my default installation that leads to `root/news`. Now if the user is located on `root/en` and clicks this link it redirects him to `root/en/news`.

We always have `/en` prefix before our original links. Or do I have to go and change all the links manually?

Comment: Can you give the same example using full URLs?

Comment: Sure, default root page link leads to: `mypage/news`, same link on /en subfolder leads to: `mypage/en/news`

Comment: Start with the http:// part? so I can tell where the domain name lies?

Comment: default root page link leads to: `http://mypage/news.php`, same link on /en subfolder should lead to: `http://mypage/en/news.php`

Comment: Is there a news.php in the / directory as well as in the /en/ directory?

Comment: yes in both directories the same install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite won't work or will be extemely complex because you have the same files in both directories.  So Apache won't know how to tell which link you clicked unless you change all the links.  The quick way to change the base URL for all the links in your pages is to use the `<base>` tag.  Note that it will change the base URL for all relative resources such as css, javascript and images too.

If the links in your pages are relative (i.e. they don't have the http://www.example.com part), then you can use the `<base>` tag to set the base URL for all resources on the page.  See:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

All of your pages in the /en/ directory should have a `<base>` tag that sets the base URL, and your links should start with `/`.

Example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://example.com/en/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/news.php">news</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of an apache redirect to a subdirectory, but I don't think it works in yoru case.  Browsers will not be able to access anything in the / directory this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ en [L]
```

Comment: thanks for that .htaccess part! If I type `http://mypage` I am indeed redirected to `http://mypage/en` though is there a way to hide the `/en` part in the URL?

Comment: this answer is also great but refering to that .htaccess could you also include that and answer my above question?

Comment: Since you have the same files in both the parent and the subdirectory, that's not going to work.  How would Apache know you want to be in the /en/ directory if it's not in the URL?

Comment: funny as it may be you actually answered 2 of my problems, if you could just tell me how to hide a part of my url that would be a double win :)